# Ring and modules

Tags: group-theory

Lemma. 
The following conditions are equivalent

1. A set C satisfies the ascending chain condition
2. For any infinite ascending chain Cα1 ⊆ Cα2 ⊆ . . . in the family, there exists an integer n such that Cαn = Cαn+1 = . . . (the chain stabilizes).
3. Any nonempty subfamily of the given infinite family has a maximal member y, that is for any element x of the subfamily which contains y we have x=y.

A family of subsets {Cα}α∈S of a set C is said to satisfy the ascending chain condition (ACC) if there does not exist an infinite strictly ascending chain
￼￼￼￼in the family.

Proof. 
(1) =⇒ (2): Assume that for a given infinite family there is no such n, then it is an infinite strictly ascending chain, a contradiction.

(2) =⇒ (3): Let x be an element of the subfamily. If x is not maximal, it is properly contained in a element x1 of the subfamily. If x1 is not maximal, it is properly contained in an element x2 and so on. In this way we construct an infinite strictly ascending chain, which leads to a contardiction.

I do not know how to prove that (3) implies (1)??

Comment: ""A set C""?? I think you're not giving the whole information needed. What are the $\,a_i$'s, for example? What does $\,Ca_i\,$ mean?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is a strictly ascending chain $X\subsetneq X'\subsetneq X''\cdots$. Is there a maximal member of the family $\{{X,X',X'',\dots\}}$?